# In which cases the spectrum of an operator contains only eigenvalues?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

Let $X\neq \{0\}$ be a complex normed spaces (not necessarily finite-dimensional) and $T:D(T)\subset X\to X$ a closed linear operator (not necessarily bounded). I would like to know under what conditions can we conclude that every spectral value $\lambda\neq 0$ of $T$ is, is fact, an eigenvalue of $T$.

For example, a common condition is: $T$ compact and $D(T)=X$ (see [Kreyszig](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599), p. 420). Are there some other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another condition: $X$ is Banach and $T$ has compact resolvent (see [Engel](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=One-Parameter+Semigroups+for+Linear+Evolution+Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC-OThvM_TAhVKHJAKHWi2AwcQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=One-Parameter%20Semigroups%20for%20Linear%20Evolution%20Equations&f=false), p. 248).

**Remark.** $T$ having compact resolvent means that $(\lambda - T)^{-1}$ is a comapct operator for some $\lambda\in\rho(T)$, which is the case if and only if the embedding $(D(T),\|\cdot\|_{D(T)})\to |(X,\|\cdot\|_X)$ is compact (see [Engel](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=One-Parameter+Semigroups+for+Linear+Evolution+Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC-OThvM_TAhVKHJAKHWi2AwcQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=One-Parameter%20Semigroups%20for%20Linear%20Evolution%20Equations&f=false), p. 117).